# OpenCV 2.4.4 and GPU support for face detection

Tags: c, opencv, cuda, gpu, face-detection

I am using GPU for faster face detection. I have found an acceptable tutorial [here](http://barkingbogart.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/face-detection-with-opencv-gpu-version/). I am using VC10 compiler along with CUDA 4.2. The device is well installed and devicequery passes the tests. I also have written programs in CUDA which leaves me no choice but to say that OpenCV has problems with GPU. The real problem is an access violation when I try to get an instance of CascadeClassifier_GPU. Also, getCudaEnabledDeviceCount returns zero. I have compiled OpenCV with CUDA flag on and there was no serious problem during the compilation only a python interface failed which is absolutely non-relevant to GPU. Is there anyone out there who actually succeeded in running a face detection code with haar features on a GPU with OpenCV? Can you give me a hint about what I am missing?

Comment: You should post a minimal example, or at least some code and the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with OpenCV CMake. The output directory is assumed to be the /build directory however once you check it, you see that all files in the /build are old. You should gather new dll and lib files from /bin and /lib. This is a major flaw in my opinion since many people will use the old files and think their compile was unsuccessful. Please also note that the CUDA version must be 4.2.9 both SDK and Toolkit once you are building the project. Now GPU module works just fine for me.